# row values @ each iteration

Tags: math

Im creating a matrix in a loop, for example

```
for i= 1:10
   Create a matrix A (dimension 50 x 6)
end i
```

I would like to see the values from row 1 to row 10 for every iteration. For example

row1
iteration1:  x y z 1 2 3
iteration2:  a b c 5 6 7
and so on

and similarly for row 2 to row 10.
I dont want to create 10 variable inside the loop to append the values at the end of each iteration. how can we do this with minimum variable? 
I may be also interested in the row values of 30 to 45 in future.

Comment: Do you need to get those values during creation loop or in another loop?

Comment: @learner are you creating 10 matrices ? can you clarify what you mean by iteration and rows ?

Comment: @ricky at each iteration im creating a new A matrix. i would like to find the values of row 1 to 10 from the A matrix at each iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without using additional variables. The best way is to either store the 10 matrices in an array and loop through that, or to store the 10 rows you're printing out and append in your `i-loop` (like you said). The latter method is more memory efficient.